# R and Regression: How to determine distribution of residuals?

Tags: r, regression, distributions, residuals

I have residuals from a linear regression model on my data set. I want to find an appropriate distribution of my residuals.

1. Say, I assume my residuals are Skew-T Distributed, how can I find the (best)
   distribution parameters by Fitting?
2. If the sample distribution of my residuals indicate bimodality, how can I determine an appropriate distribution?
3. How can I model kurtotic behaviour and long (but not heavy) tails of my residuals ?
4. How can I do this in R?
5. How can I model Heteroscedasticity of data?

Comment: Can you explain 3 more? Skew T and most other distributions go to infinity, so they have infinitely long, non-heavy tails. Also is it 2 questions? I don't see how you can have excess kurtosis  without it affecting the tails. Is it that you light tails?

Comment: Can you more clearly explain the intended distinction between *long* and *heavy*?

Comment: Thank you for adding the plots.  Could you tell us more about where the data come from?

Comment: The (linear regression) models, where the residuals come from, should model a linear relationship between Deviance of Height of an aircraft and some other covariates (1. density plot) and Speed of an aircraft to some covariates (2. density plot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could model the residuals and get estimates using maximum likelihood.  Here's a simple example:

```
N <- 500
df <- data.frame(x=runif(N, 0, 50))
df$y <- 10 + 2 * df$x + 4 * rt(N, 4)  # True params
plot(df$x, df$y)

ll <- function(params) {
    ## Log likelihood for y ~ x + student's t errors
    params <- as.list(params)
    return(sum(dt((df$y - params$const - params$beta*df$x) / params$scale,
                      df=params$degrees.freedom, log=TRUE) - log(params$scale)))
}

optim_result <- optim(par=c(const=5, beta=1, scale=3, degrees.freedom=5),
                      lower=c(-Inf, -Inf, 0.1, 0.1),
                      fn=ll, method="L-BFGS-B", control=list(fnscale=-1), hessian=TRUE)
fit <- data.frame(coefficient=optim_result$par, se=sqrt(diag(solve(-optim_result$hessian))))
```

That's a linear regression with student's-t errors.

If your residuals are bimodal, you could try a mixture of two normals.

Edit:  for mixtures of regressions in R, see ftp://www.r-project.org/pub/R/web/packages/mixtools/vignettes/mixtools.pdf.